# How to install newer version of libwacom-common (Ubuntu 18.04)? *updated

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies, tablet, wacom

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04 MATE bionic and the libwacom-common version already installed is 0.29-1. Unfortunately my Wacom tablet needs at least version 0.30 to be able to run wacom-gui correctly.

I did remove the old libwacom-common, but when I try to install a newer one, more exactly version 0.32-1, as a deb file I've got from Launchpad, GDebi won't be able to install it, saying "Error: Breaks existing package 'libwacom2' dependency libwacom-common (=0.29-1), although I already uninstalled libwacom2 before as well.

I appreciate any help how to accomplish this, thanks.

More info about libwacom and wacom-gui:

https://github.com/linuxwacom/libwacom/wiki

https://github.com/linuxwacom/input-wacom/wiki/Device-IDs (mine is PTZ-631W)

https://github.com/linuxwacom/xf86-input-wacom/wiki/External-Applications#graphical-configuration-tools

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to compile all [Wacom packages](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/bionic/libwacom) from Ubuntu 19.04 source.
At first enable *Source code* repositories in *Software & Updates* (`software-properties-gtk`) and then run:

```
# get build dependencies
sudo apt-get build-dep libwacom
# get tools
sudo apt-get install build-essential dpkg-dev debhelper devscripts

# download source codes
cd ~/Downloads 
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libw/libwacom/libwacom_0.32-1.dsc
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libw/libwacom/libwacom_0.32.orig.tar.gz
tar -xf libwacom_0.32.orig.tar.gz
cd libwacom-*
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libw/libwacom/libwacom_0.32-1.debian.tar.xz
tar -xf libwacom_0.32-1.debian.tar.xz

# compile deb-packages from source code
dpkg-buildpackage -b --no-sign

# install resulting deb-packages
sudo apt install ../libwacom*.deb
```

So you will get LibWacom 0.32-1 installed on your system.

If this does not help - then you can revert packages installation with command below:

```
sudo apt-get install libwacom-bin=0.29-1 libwacom-common=0.29-1 libwacom-dev=0.29-1 \
libwacom2:amd64=0.29-1 libwacom2-dbg:amd64=0.29-1
```

to have ordinary 0.29-1 from Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.